# const vector<string> or const string[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

In my class I need to store a `const static` set of strings. As the code being written now in C++ is based on original C algorithms (in part), the data was stored as `const char* presets[150]` (there are 150 strings).  As I am now essentially rewriting/repackaging this in C++, `char*` became `string`.  My question is: should I change the array to `vector`?

What's better in this case, `const static vector<string> presets` or `const static string presets[150]`?

Comment: If you have C++11 available, `std::array<std::string, 150>` would be the best option.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say. If not, stick with the vector.

Comment: @Angew Hm... `std::array` is defined as `template<typename T, int size> struct std::array { T a[size]; };` so what's the advantage of using `std::array<std::string, 150> presets` over `std::string presets[150]` (besides just using this syntax).

Comment: @AleksG, For starters, it doesn't decay to a pointer.

Comment: @AleksG: `.size()` and proper value semantics

Comment: I am wondering why the data stored as const char* data[150] has to change at all?

Comment: @arrows because it's C, not C++, and it's fugly

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz On the other hand, it works, and all of the C++ alternatives have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it in fact `char const* const presets[] = { ... };`,
initialized with string literals?  In other words, when you say
`char const* presents[150]`, is this because someone forgot the
second `const`, or is it because you actually modify the
pointers later.  And is it because someone actually counted the
initializers, and put the number in the braces, and you update
this number each time you add or remove an initializer, or is it
because you provide less initializers, and count on the trailing
values being initialized with a nul pointer?  Without knowing
exactly what you're trying to do, it's difficult giving good
recommendations.

In the most frequent case I've encountered, where what you
really want is that everything be const, and that the size of
the array correspond exactly to the number of initializers, the
best solution is probably to just leave it as it is.  To get
automatic sizing of the array, you need to use either C style
arrays, or (and then only with C++11) `std::vector`;
`std::array` requires you to explicitly give the number of
elements.  And to get truly static initialization (and thus
*never* have any risk of order of initialization issues), you
need either a C style array or `std::array`, in both cases of
`char const*` (and not `std::string`, which requires dynamic
initialization).

Note that using `char const*` rather than `std::string` does
mean that each time you access it (typically), you will
construct a new `std::string`.  Depending on the implementation,
this *may* introduce some extra runtime overhead.  Usually, this
is not a problem, but it may be something to consider as well;
it has to be weighed against the fact that if you use the object
from constructors of other static objects, using `std::string`
will cause order of initialization issues which would have to be
addresses.

Comment: And that's why I recommended `array<string>` instead of `array<const char*>`. Assuming we aren't on embedded (which, I guess would be tagged appropriately), memory is less of a concern than computing power.

Comment: +1 for "what you really want is that everything be const, and that the size of the array correspond exactly to the number of initializers, the best solution is probably to just leave it as it is".

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The problem remains that `std::string` does not allow static initialization, and so can cause order of initialization issues.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not the latter.

If the size doesn't need to change, use

```
std::array<std::string, 150>
```

This way you will be able to operate on it in a very similar way to `std::vector`.

EDIT: Regarding possible problems with `string` initialization: You can create the array as C-style array, and then copy the data to an `array`. Since you will be copying contiguos block of (around) 600 bytes, it isn't very expensive operation.

Comment: `std::string[]` can also use the standard algorithms …

Comment: @KonradRudolph Still, the `array` is preferred. The fact C-style arrays can be used with standard algorithms is more for backwards compatibility and ease of integrating old code.

Comment: Hm... `std::array` is defined as `template<typename T, int size> struct std::array { T a[size]; };` so what's the advantage of using `std::array<std::string, 150> presets` over `std::string presets[150]` (besides just using this syntax).

Comment: @AleksG The advantage is that `std::array` behaves as a proper type whereas raw arrays like to throw away type information at the drop of a hat. Consider: `void foo(int arr[10]) {} int main() { int arr[3]; foo(arr); }` This does not result in any compile time error because of some awful rules imported from C.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Whether `std::array` is preferred or not depends on the context.  If you use `std::array`, you have to carefully count the initializers, and specify the size as an integral constant.  If you use `std::string[]`, the compiler will do this for you, with no chance of error.  And unless you're actually passing the full array as an argument to a function, the fact that arrays are broken as a type doesn't matter much.

Comment: @James You can trivially define a `constexpr make_array` function to do this for you though. Although I’m not quite sure why this obvious piece is so glaringly missing from the standard library.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Copying doesn't change the order of initialization issue, since it is a dynamic operation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you use a array or vector of std::string you have to deal with initialisation of objects at runtime. If you use your original array everything is initialised at compile time. On the other side it may be usefull to use "real" objects when you need additional functionality like a constant time size() .